# How to use Json in Flot for ploting graph?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flot

I'm using [Flot Graph Api](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) to display bar chart, line chart in my clien side php. I try to pass Json to plot graph as they have mentioned in their examples.

I pack the Json like this,

```
 [{"label":"63f9311f-5d33-66ad-dcc1-353054485572","bars":{"show":true},"data":        [[-170.44530493708,270.44530493708]]},{"label":"8f6dcf4a-b20c-8059-1410-353054486037","bars":{"show":true},"data":[[-791.50048402711,891.50048402711]]},{"label":"c2b4cf75-3e0b-f9ff-722e-353054485803","bars":{"show":true},"data":[[-1280.0484027106,1380.0484027106]]},{"label":"eb963e23-75cd-6131-867a-353054485894","bars":{"show":true},"data":[[-1487.2604065828,1587.2604065828]]},{"label":"ef413106-d5be-593b-1cda-353054485719","bars":{"show":true},"data":[[-1940.9583736689,2040.9583736689]]}]
```

But the graph is not ploting.

```
     $.ajax({                                      
  url: '../c/By_Machine_Controller.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
  data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                   //for example "id=5&parent=6"
  dataType: 'json',                //data format      
  success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var Up = [];
    var Down = [];
    Up = data[0];              //get Up
    Down = data[1];           //get Down
    //alert(Up);
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ Up , Down ]);
  } 
});
```

Is it anything to do with Json or My JS is wrong. Since, i am new to flot i don't have any clue. Can anyone help me out.

The Answer i have entered works fine, but in this case, i'm writing the JSON into a temp file and accessing it, but my requirement is,

I calculate the values for the flot in MODEL Folder in my localhost and passing it as associative array and encoding it as a JSON in CONTROLLER Folder. Now i need to access the JSON in VIEW Folder in my localhost.

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
    $json = json_encode($allData);
    $myFile = "ReasonByTime.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
    fwrite($fh, $json);

    fclose($fh);
```

But when i access the $json of the CONTROLLER in the VIEW through JS like the following, its not working. I googled it but i was not able to fix it. Can you help me out with this?

VIEW JS CODE TO ACCESS JSON From CONTROLLER.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

    //var dataurl = '../c/By_Machine_Controller.php';

    function onDataReceived(data) {

        $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../c/By_Machine_Controller.php',
        data: 'data',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @ThusithaSumanadasa: code spans (`like this`) are not for emphasis or highlighting: they're only meant for code within sentences. Please don't use them for words like `JSON` or `JavaScript`, but stuff like variable names are alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('ReasonByTime.txt', function(json) {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"),json, {bars: { show: true, barWidth:0.2},xaxis: {ticks: json.ticks}});
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Looks nice, you can add `barWidth` if you need like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YHPea/ OR page with example: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/stacking.html

Flot library fill all space, that's why you get such result: http://jsfiddle.net/YHPea/1/

Comment: If i give data directly, its working fine for me. but, how to extract data from Json to plot graph.

Comment: @Allen I miss something, but this ( http://jsfiddle.net/YHPea/2/ ) works for me or you talking about something else

Comment: The problem is, its an Json/Associative array, it is a dynamic value, i can't give the value directly like this ` var data = [{"label":"63f9311f-5d33-66ad-dcc1-353054485572","bars":{"show":true},"data":        [[-170.44530493708,270.44530493708]]},{"label":"8f6dcf4a-b20c-8059-1410-353054486037","bars":{"show":true},"data":[[-791.50048402711,891.50048402711]]},{"label":"c2b4cf75-3e0b-f9ff-722e-353054485803","bars":{"show":true},"data":[[-1280.0484027106,1380.0484027106]]}` i should use Json object. i need some thing like this `var data = $json`.

Comment: @Allen Now I understand, if server return json, you can use it in this function `success: function(data)` <- `data` is json object here, check your response, maybe you need http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing, simply

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), data);
```

works for me.